# Adding a border to <UL> in drop-down menu

Tags: css

I am trying to configure a CSS-based drop-down menu.

I have added a border around `<UL>` and would like it to be the container for all `<li>` elemets.
It works fine until one of the `<li>` is longer than the rest. It pushes outside outside `<UL>` border.

How can I fix it?

Also, the text withing `<li>` disappears in IE, while everything works great in FF.

Here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DqTyh/4/). *(hover mouse over items)*

Comment: What would you want to happen in case of an item who's longer than the width you've set on the main LI?

Comment: The box needs to be the width of the longest item. And the items withing the box need to adjust to the width of the box. I am hoping to accomplish this with CSS only, without using JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently have set `width:100%` to your submenu dropdown, this will only be `100%` of the parent container which is smaller than your submenu list item that is overflowing your container due to your `white-space:nowrap` property. Simply remove that width declaration and your submenu should expand with its inner content.

```
#nav ul {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 598;
}
```

Also, you don't want to float left your submenu items so you can move that property to where you're using your child selector.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DqTyh/8/

Answer (score 1):

Other than `float`, `display` and `postion`, move all of your styling from the `LI` tag to the `A` tag and use `display:block` on the `A` tag.

See my tutorial: http://preview.moveable.com/JM/ilovelists/

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're declaring a set width on your menu item. Which causes a constraint in any inner elements. Since they are wider, they have no choice but to push out of the border.

Remove the set width, and you should be fine.